# How to route URLs like /controller/action-name to controller/action_name in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes

I want my URLs use '-' but the C# method name cannot contains that character. How do I make this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define a new route handler which handles the hyphens before the controller and action elements are mapped to class and methods. Check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070890/asp-net-mvc-support-for-urls-with-hyphens)