# How to make the controller's name hyphen "-" separated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am able to use the

```
[ActionName("My-Action-Name")]
public ActionResult MyActionName()
{
    return View();
}
```

But I am facing a problem in changing the controller's Name.
Is there some annotation available to make controller name hyphen (-) separated in MVC 4?

Somewhat like this:

```
[ControllerName("My-Controller-Name")]
public class MyControllerName : Controller
{

}
```

Comment: This is a matter of routing, not renaming. You should do this when defining your routes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070890/asp-net-mvc-support-for-urls-with-hyphens) is a good answer:

Add custom route handler (in replace part choose how you want to handle hyphens):

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "");
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "");
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

and use it in your `RouteConfig`

```
routes.Add(
        new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
        );
```

Comment: In case you need a route name, see [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32716734/456456) for a alternative using MapRoute.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx).

It comes in MVC 5 as well.

You can find some examples below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

```
[RoutePrefix("Book-Reviews")]
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    // eg.: /reviews
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }
    // eg.: /reviews/5
    [Route("{reviewId}")]
    public ActionResult Show(int reviewId) { ... }
    // eg.: /reviews/5/edit
    [Route("{reviewId}/edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int reviewId) { ... }
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to provide a couple of examples rather than just a link.

Comment: Attribute routing *only* works in MVC 5. You can't use it in MVC 4

Comment: There is a nuget package for that. yes you can.

Comment: Then the answer should make it explicit that it *doesn't* refer to ASP.NET MVC's attribute routing, but a 2 year old nuget package. The two implementations are *not* compatible. The OP may prefer to upgrade to MVC 5 instead of facing the migration issues later on

Comment: why dont you provide an answer with those details? I will +1.

Comment: Guys, We can do this in RouteConfig.cs file, by overriding some method, but I am not able to do that right away. Although I have seen the solution in one of my previous project, but no luck now. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer of @aleha, but wanted to do this for MapRoute, because I need a route name.

In such cases, you can do this:

```
    Route route = routes.MapRoute(
        "RouteName",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    route.RouteHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @R. Schreurs solutions. This is what my RouteConfig class looks like now and my controller name now works with a hyphen.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "");
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "");
            return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();
    }
}
```