# How to allow page names with hyphens in dotnet core

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, naming-conventions

I am using dotnet Core 3.1 and saw in my Controllers that a page name can not contain special characters (which is fine if you start a project from scratch).

If you got tasked with taking over an existing website and have page names that contains hyphens i.e. top-ten-pupils-in-matric, how can one go about in achieving this in dotnet core 3.1?

Please see the example below in what I would like to achieve

```
public IActionResult top-ten-pupils-in-matric()
{
        return View();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Route attribute `[Route("Home/my-dashed-url")`

Comment: .. or perhaps a [RouteHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176087/how-to-make-the-controllers-name-hyphen-separated)?

Comment: Thank you so much, Train and stuartd! Works like a charm :)

Comment: I would probably search and replace that with a more modern naming convention. Such as `TopTenPupilsInMatric()`.