# Razor file name with a dash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need my page names to have a dash in the name. E.G our-vision

I'm new to MVC & c# so I may be going about all this wrong.

Here is my controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        // GET: /our-vision/
        public ActionResult ourVision()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And then in my views, I have Views/Home/ourVision.cshtml.

When I compile and go to `http://localhost/ourVision` it works, but when I go to `http://localhost/our-vision` it does not.

Here is my routing:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-enable-dashes-in-my-urls

Comment: He's using mvc and not using Razor.

Comment: @CharliePrynn Umm, MVC is the framework and Razor is one of many possible view engines that can be used with MVC. The solution still applies since it's core MVC stuff.

Comment: It's solved in the controller using the name attribute :)

Comment: @yuck is right, this has nothing to do with RAZOR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do a few things in order to achieve that.

First, to achieve `our-Vision`, you'll need to give your action method the `ActionName` attribute, like so:

```
[ActionName("our-Vision")]
public ActionResult ourVision()
```

Next, you'll have to rename your `ourVision.cshtml` view to be `our-Vision.cshtml`

Finally, whenever you're using `Url.Action` or `ActionLink`, you need to use `our-Vision` and **not** `vision`, like so:

```
Url.Action("our-Vision", "Home");
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO

The best way to do this - is define new route in route engine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "OurVision", // Route name
            "our-vision", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "ourVision" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```