# ASP.NET MVC 4 Override Controller Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to override the controller name in ASP.NET MVC 4?
It's needed for routing.

There is `[ActionName("some-action-name")]` attribute to override the action name.

Is it possible to do the same for a controller class name?

It's needed to make a controller name in the routing to have dashes, like "some-controller-name" instead of "SomeControllerName"

Comment: I think that is not possible, because controller must be a unique to simple routing.

Comment: Try to add in Global.asax

Comment: Controller action names are also unique, but they have ActionNameAttribute that allows to override it.

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that, you could just put a new one previous to the default one so it's get checked first. It would look like this (I have not tested it however): `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyName",
                url: "this-is-dashed/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ThisIsNotDashed", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: Looks like you want to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2454016/351614

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved with routes. It's the only way to do it.

Thanks for comments.