# Override controller name in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, attributerouting

Similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831869/asp-net-mvc-4-override-controller-name), but for the new ASP.NET Core.

I can override an action's routing name:

```
[ActionName("Bar")]
public IActionResult Foo() {
```

Can I do that for a controller, using attribute routing?

```
[?("HelloController")]
public SomeController : Controller {
```

It should allow generation of links using tag helpers:

```
<a asp-controller="some" ...      // before
<a asp-controller="hello" ...     // after
```

Comment: I use [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")] with [ApiVersion("1.0")]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Such an attribute does not exist. But you can create one yourself:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ControllerNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ControllerNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Apply it on your controller:

```
[ControllerName("Test")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Then create a custom controller convention:

```
public class ControllerNameAttributeConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        var controllerNameAttribute = controller.Attributes.OfType<ControllerNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (controllerNameAttribute != null)
        {
            controller.ControllerName = controllerNameAttribute.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

And add it to MVC conventions in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(mvc =>
{
    mvc.Conventions.Add(new ControllerNameAttributeConvention());
});
```

Now `HomeController` Index action will respond at `/Test/Index`. Razor tag helper attributes can be set as you wanted.

Only downside is that at least ReSharper gets a bit broken in Razor. It is not aware of the convention so it thinks the `asp-controller` attribute is wrong.

Comment: I know it's been quite long time ago, but anyway thank you for the answer - it's very helpful. Can you please tell me how to rename controller name, but folder in Views remains in old name?

Comment: @svstnv you could try something like this ----            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/YourLocation/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension));

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to derive the controller name from the Controller class (Classname minus Controller surfix), then just leave out the `[controller]` place holder.

```
[Route("/api/hello")]
public SomeController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() { }

    [HttpGet("something")]
    public IActionResult GetSomething() { }
}
```

The overloads in `HttpGet` will set the action name. Doing so however, you can't use generic routes like

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
```

or you have to register them manually there

```
routes.MapRoute("hello", "api/hello/{id?}", defaults: new { controller = "Hello" });
routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is code we are using

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MembersController : Controller { /* */ }
```

Comment: What is the name of the controller in this case? And could I use it for generating links?

Comment: `[controller]` is a placeholder which will be replaced by the controller class name minus the word "Controller", so "Members".

Comment: Yeah but I needed to *change* the name of the controller, so this doesn't do it.

Comment: @grokky - Then fill it in with the name you want i.e. [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Member")]

Answer (score 2):

It should be the same way that you would do it in ASP.NET WebAPI2 before Core:

```
[Route("Bar")]
public IActionResult Foo() { }
```

If you're looking to do it on the Controller level as well, there's a different attribute for that:

```
[RoutePrefix("ControllerFoo")]
public class MyController() { }
```

[Here](http://dotnetthoughts.net/attribute-routing-in-aspnet-core/) is a (non-Microsoft) article that goes over how it should be done in .NET Core.

Comment: Does it matter when you are doing tag helpers? I have some controllers that "don't make sense", but I've modified the routes to look relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately it matters because I'd need to refactor dozens of views. I was hoping for a way to just perform a rename in one place. Also, all the controller's actions already specify a route. I need this specifically to work with tag helpers.