# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Clean Urls - from camel case to hyphenated words

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I currently have an action defined in my controller:

```
    // GET: /schools/:cleanUrlName/data-loggers
    public ActionResult DataLoggers(string cleanUrlName)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This works when I hit "/schools/brisbane-state-high-school/dataloggers", however - as per the comment - I want to access it via a slightly cleaner url (using hyphens): "/schools/brisbane-state-high-school/data-loggers". I know I could write a route to accomplish this, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to write a new route for every multi-worded action/controller. Is there a better way to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ActionNameAttribute` to create an alias for your action name.

So you just need to annotate your multi worded actions:

```
[ActionName("data-loggers")]
public ActionResult DataLoggers(string cleanUrlName)
{
    return View("DataLoggers");
}
```

But because this affects also the view discovery therefore you need to return `View("DataLoggers")` so you are probably better with creating custom routes for your multi worded actions.

Comment: If you want some more generic solution, you can have a look on the IIS url rewriting feature or you can derive from `Route` and remove the hyphens for the action name with overriding the `GetRouteData` method...

Comment: Excellent! I think I'll use `ActionName` since it is just one line compared to the several lines required per route. I feel the `RouteConfig` would get quite large if I I wrote a route for each multi-word action. Thanks.

Comment: i am no longer able to add  view with `dash` as said [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1998192.aspx?Can+no+longer+add+views+with+periods+in+the+name+Visual+Studio+Pro+2013+) , when tried this appears:  `The name is not allowed to contain any of these characters: . - @ <`, . so i guess only solution is to rename the view after adding