# Using Route Attributes In ASP.NET MVC 5 With Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This question pertains to ASP.NET MVC 5.

I'm trying to use hyphens in my URLs by using route attributes, but I'm not having any luck getting it to work. [I'm using this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-enable-dashes-in-my-urls) and [this MSDN blog reference.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) This URLs I want to have are:

```
/my-test/
/my-test/do-something
```

When I build my project and bring the page I'm testing up in a browser, I'm getting a 404 error. Here is the code I have so far:

```
// RouteConfig.cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        ...
    }
}

// MyTestController.cs - NOTE: THIS FILE IS IN AN AREA
[RouteArea("MyTest")]
[RoutePrefix("my-test")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class MyTestController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/do-something")]
    public JsonResult DoSomething(string output)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Output = output
        });
    }

    [Route]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

// Index.cshtml
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // I'm using an ajax call to test the DoSomething() controller.
        // div1 should display "Hello, World!"
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/product-management/do-something",
            data: {
                output: "Hello, World!"
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            $("div1").html(response.output);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

When I created the area, an area registration file was created and I had all my route information in that file, but according to the MSDN blog, I can remove that file and rely entirely upon the route attributes.

Comment: What does it mean - "testing in browser"?

Comment: I was testing my code in a browser to see it my route attributes were working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The class needed the following RouteAreaAttribute:

```
[RouteArea("MyTest", AreaPrefix = "my-test")]
public class MyTestController : Controller
{ 
    ...
}
```

This allowed me to delete the area route registration file too!