# Using Route Attributes In MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

First of all, I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-enable-dashes-in-my-urls) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804701/using-route-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-5-with-areas) 
I think I have another problem. Because everything is the same.

I have MVC5 project. I have 2 areas.
First, my default root class like this.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
      routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

**first area route config.**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "App_default",
        "App/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

At this point, there is no problem. But I want like this:

This App/Controller

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    // GET: App/Accounts
    [Route("app/accounts/list/{Id}")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now, I can access like :

- localhost/Index/Index *OK*
- localhost/App/Index/Index *OK*
- localhost/app/accounts/list/45646 *ERROR*

How can I route attribute using Areas? I cannot do it?

Comment: `[Route("app/accounts/list/{Id}")]` Change to `[Route("App/accounts/list/{Id}")]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to receive an integer as a parameter in the List ActionResult in order for 'localhost/app/accounts/list/45646' URL to work.

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
 {
     // GET: App/Accounts
     [Route("app/accounts/list/{Id}")]
     public ActionResult List(int Id)
     {

          return View();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to enable attribute routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      //Enable attribute routing
      routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

      //Area registration should be done after
      //attribute routes to avoid route conflicts
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

      //convention-based routing
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
      );
}
```

And then add the proper attributes to the controller

```
[RouteArea("AreaName", AreaPrefix = "app/accounts")]
public class AccountsController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("list/{id:int}")] // Matches GET app/accounts/list/45646
    public ActionResult List(int id) {
        return View();
    }
}
```