# Can I give SEO-friendly URL Segment's to action on a PageController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver, episerver-8

Is it possible to define the URL segment for an action on a `PageController<T>`?

Take for example the following controller,

```
public class MyPageController : PageController<MyPageData>
{
    public ActionResult Index(MyPageData currentPage)
    {
        return View(currentPage);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitForm(MyPageData currentPage, FormModel model)
    {
        // ...
        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

New, let's say we've created an instance of `MyPageData` at the URL `/my-page`, if we render a form who's action is the `SubmitForm` action, we'll get a URL like so `<form action="/my-page/SubmitForm">`

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm"))
{
    ...
}
```

My question is, is there any way to define or control how the URL segment for the non-Index action is rendered, so the form would render like so `<form action="/my-page/submit-form">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the standard ASP.NET action name attribute, such as

```cs
public class MyPageController : PageController<MyPageData>
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("submit-form")]
    public ActionResult SubmitForm(MyPageData currentPage, FormModel model)
    {
        // ...
        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-enable-dashes-in-my-urls) to make **seo friendly url**