# Create custom endpoint in a MVC .NET project with hyphen

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to create an endpoint for something like this: `https://www.example.com/hyphen-param?id=123`

I've tried using `MapHttpRoute` `MapPageRoute` `[Route("hyphen-param", HttpVerbs.Get)]` `[RoutePrefix("{hyphen-param}")]`

I need the Class name to have a hyphen not just a route within the class.

Nothing has worked so far, any insight would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.Net MVC: How do I enable dashes in my urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-enable-dashes-in-my-urls)

Comment: @Chris.ZA this isn't a duplicate of that question because that stackoverflow doesn't answer how to make the class name hyphen. I want the url to look like https://www.example.com/hyphen-param?id=123